# Suggest deploy path in a Grunt task

Tags: gruntjs, webstorm

I have a Grunt task to automatize the deploy of my webapp on webserver.
On My webserver I have 3 paths:

- /www/myApp    (production)
- /www/myApp_rc

I have a `package.json` file

```
{
 ...
  "ftpDeployPath":"myApp_rc"   //or /www/myApp
...
}
```

and this is my task

```
{'ftp-deploy': {
                toMyServer: {
                    auth: {
                        host: '10.7.88.87',
                        port: 21,
                        authKey: 'key1'
                    },

                    src: 'deploy',
                    dest: '<%= pkg.ftpDeployPath %>',
                    forceVerbose: true
                }
            }
```

}

When I want deploy, every time I have to check and eventually edit `package.json` file.
Is there any way to show a prompt (bu grunt console) to allow me to select the right deploy path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably try using [grunt-prompt](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-prompt) task with 'input' question type and your "ftpDeployPath" as 'config'. Or, modify your gruntfile to use command line options (http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#dynamic-alias-tasks) and run your tasks as external tools from WebStorm (Settings | Tools | External tools) - you can add $Prompt$ macro to tool parameters to get a prompt for option value when running a tool

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of command line arguments and a custom task, you can modify configuration for tasks before you run them.  Let's start first by modifying the template string for `dist`; change it to access a `grunt.option()` param called `deployPath` our custom task will set:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    'ftp-deploy': {
        toMyServer: {
            auth: {
                host: '10.7.88.87',
                port: 21,
                authKey: 'key1'
            },
            src: 'deploy',
            dest: '<%= grunt.option('deployPath') %>',
            forceVerbose: true
        }
    }
});
```

Next, craft a custom task that sets the `grunt.option('deployPath')` parameter.  The task below will set deployPath to `myApp` when you run `grunt deploy:prod`.  If you run just `grunt deploy`, the path is set to `myApp_rc`.  Once the path is chosen, the custom then calls the `ftp-deploy` task:

```
function deployTask(grunt) {
    var deployPath = (this.args[0] === 'prod') ? 'myApp' : 'myApp_rc';
    grunt.option('deployPath', deployPath);
    grunt.task.run('ftp-deploy');
}

grunt.registerTask('deploy', deployTask);
```